# Почему из функции возвращается None

Tags: python, python-faq

Изучаю Python3. Реализовал рекурсивный алгоритм Евклида для поиска наибольшего общего делителя. Никак не пойму, почему функция возвращает `None`. Что самое интересное - строка `print(b)` выводит правильный результат и далее функция завершается, но результат `None`

```
def nod(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        print(b)
        return b
    elif b == 0:
        return a
    elif a > b:
        nod(a % b, b)
    else:
        nod(a, b % a)
```

Comment: А еще, у вас проблемы с отступами в теле функции (не знаю случайность это или нет).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Любая функция в Python возвращает значение. Если вы не используете инструкцию `return` явно, то функция возвращает `None`.

В вашем случае ветки условия `elif a > b` и `else` не возвращают ничего. Отсюда и берется `None`.

А вот и пример правильного, работоспособного кода (без лишнего вызова `print`):

```
def nod(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    elif b == 0:
        return a
    elif a > b:
        return nod(a % b, b)
    else:
        return nod(a, b % a)

print(nod(10, 2)) # выведет 2
```

Comment: Действительно. Просто невнимательность. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте `return` в `elif a > b:` и `else:`

```
def nod(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        print(b)
        return b
    elif b == 0:
        return a
    elif a > b:
        return nod(a % b, b)
    else:
        return nod(a, b % a)
```