# Функция с return возвращает None, с print список(массив вершин)

Tags: python

Дан двудольный ориентированный граф **graph**.Хочу сделать поиск в глубину до вершины **t**. Но когда вызываю функцию он возвращает только None. если вместо return написать print, никаких None нет. А как сделать так чтобы при return возвращал список вершин.

```py
graph={'s': ['1.1', '1.2', '1.3'], 
       '1.1': ['2.2'], 
       '1.2': ['2.1', '2.3'], 
       '1.3': [''], 
       '2.1': 't',
       '2.2': 't', 
       '2.3': 't'}
def dfs(graph,node,vis):
    vis.append(node)
    try:
        for i in graph[node]:
            if i not in vis:
                if len(vis)<4:
                    dfs(graph,i,vis)
    except:
        return vis
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Рекурсивная функция возвращает None](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481224/Рекурсивная-функция-возвращает-none)

Answer (score 5):

Очевидно потому что вы возвращаете значение из функции только когда произошла ошибка...
если исправить except на finally то все получатся... по крайней мере у меня следующий код работает

```
graph1={'s': ['1.1', '1.2', '1.3'], 
       '1.1': ['2.2'], 
       '1.2': ['2.1', '2.3'], 
       '1.3': [''], 
       '2.1': 't',
       '2.2': 't', 
       '2.3': 't'}
def dfs(graph,node,vis):
    vis.append(node)
    try:
        for i in graph[node]:
            if i not in vis:
                if len(vis)<4:
                    dfs(graph,i,vis)
    finally:
      return vis

print (dfs(graph1, 's', []))
```