# Почему моя функция возвращает None?

Tags: python, рекурсия

```
d={"a": {"f": {"tmp": {"er": 3}, "n": 10}}}
def search(d, skey):
    print("debug: ", d)
    for i in d:
        if i==skey:
            print(d[i])
            return d[i]
        else:
            search(d[i], skey)
print(search(d, 'f'))
```

Данная функция предназнасена для нахождения ключа skey в словаре.
Но она возвращает None вместо словаря в котором содержится ключ, в то время как на экран выводится словарь.
Как так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Рекурсивная функция возвращает None](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481224/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызов функции из самой себя тоже должен быть с `return` видимо:

```
else:
    return search(d[i], skey)
```

Иначе если первый `return` сработает после вызова функции самой из себя он вернёт управление в место вызова функции, и когда цикл кончится потом, функция в итоге ничего не вернёт, а значит вернёт `None`.

Comment: спасибо, невниматеоьность подвела!

Answer (score 0):

но надо еще проверку на кол-во ключей, иначе если поставить ключ 'n' будет ошибка

```
d={
    "a": {
        "f": {
            "tmp": {
                    "er": 3
                },
            "n": 10
        }
    }
}
def search(d, skey):
    print("debug: ", d)

    for i in d.keys():
        if i == skey:
            return d[i]
        else:
            return search(d[i], skey)


print(search(d, 'f'))
```

Comment: добавил проверку ключей

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'global': {'a': 10, 'b': 4, 'func': {'n': "foo", 'x': 'spam', 'func_f': {"d": 0}} }}
def search(d, skey):
    global a
    print("search(  %s  )" % d)
    for i in d:
        if i==skey:
            print("return %s" % d[i])
            return d[i]
        else:
            if type(d[i])==dict:
                return search(d[i], skey)
print(search(d, 'f')) # None
print(search(d, 'func_f')) # {'d': 0}
```

с проверкой ключей