# Выводит None в конце выполнения программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, словари, dict

Задание: Создать словарь, который содержит оценки студента за семестр (минимум
5 оценок), вывести предметы, по которым оценка «неуд».

Вот программа:

```
def DictInput(x):
    for i in range(n):
        key=input('Введите название предмета: ')
        m=int(input('Введите количество оценок (Минимум 5 оценок): '))
        if m>=5:
            for j in range(m):
                val=int(input('Добавьте оценку: '))
                if key not in x:
                    x[key]=list()
                    x[key].append(val)
                else:
                    x[key].append(val)
    return x
        
student=dict()
n=int(input('Введите количество предметов: '))

student=DictInput(student)

print(student)

def Check(x):    
    for i in x.keys():
        extra=x.get(i)
        if 2 in extra or 1 in extra:
            print(i)

print(Check(student))
```

Пример выполнения:

```
Введите количество предметов: 1
Введите название предмета: 1
Введите количество оценок (Минимум 5 оценок): 5
Добавьте оценку: 1
Добавьте оценку: 2
Добавьте оценку: 3
Добавьте оценку: 4
Добавьте оценку: 5
{'1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
1
None
>>>
```

Вопрос - как убрать этот None в конце?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Почему из функции возвращается None](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481224/1365)

Comment: Не дубликат, т.к. ответы оттуда не решают проблему в из этого вопроса. Можно конечно заменить print в функции на return, но тогда функция будет возвращать только один результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите из строки `print(Check(student))` (последней) `print`:

```
Check(student)
```